# Android Java Bottom navigation menu renders fragments only when I click twice on the navigation icon

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my Android app mainactivity.xml, I am using bottom navigation bar with few menu items. For each menu item, I am trying to render a fragment.  The menu items and the fragments are rendering correctly on the app.  However, to render any fragment, I have to click on the menu item **twice**.   I am using the following code on my onCreate method of mainactivity.java.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    ImageButton menuButton;
    BankLedger bankLedger;
    Members members;
    Transactions transactions;
    Vendors vendors;

    TextView mainFragmentName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bankLedger = new BankLedger();
        members = new Members();
        transactions = new Transactions();
        vendors = new Vendors();
        
        mainFragmentName = findViewById(R.id.main_fragment_name);
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.main_bottomNavView);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnItemReselectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemReselectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.bn_bank_ledger) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frameLayout,bankLedger).commit();
                    mainFragmentName.setText("BANK LEDGER");
                }
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.bn_member) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frameLayout, members).commit();
                    mainFragmentName.setText("MEMBERS");
                }
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.bn_transactions) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frameLayout,transactions).commit();
                    mainFragmentName.setText("TRANSACTIONS");
                }
                if (item.getItemId() == R.id.bn_vendors) {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frameLayout,vendors).commit();
                    mainFragmentName.setText("VENDORS");
                }
            }
        });
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.bn_bank_ledger);
    } //end of oncreate method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `OnItemReselectedListener` which get's invoked when you select same item again. Replace it with `OnItemSelectedListener` which get's invoked when you click on the item for the first time.

```java
bottomNavigationView.setOnItemReselectedListener(new NavigationBarView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
           if (item.getItemId() == R.id.bn_bank_ledger) {
               getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frameLayout,bankLedger).commit();
               mainFragmentName.setText("BANK LEDGER");
           }
           if (item.getItemId() == R.id.bn_member) {
               getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frameLayout, members).commit();
               mainFragmentName.setText("MEMBERS");
           }
           if (item.getItemId() == R.id.bn_transactions) {
               getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frameLayout,transactions).commit();
               mainFragmentName.setText("TRANSACTIONS");
           }
           if (item.getItemId() == R.id.bn_vendors) {
               getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_frameLayout,vendors).commit();
               mainFragmentName.setText("VENDORS");
           }
           return true;
       }
});
```